# how to get runtime status of http triggered azure function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am trying to build azure http triggered function which will execute user submitted code and return output. Is there anyway I can check runtime status of each invocation using invocationId in function REST API?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. In its current form, your question is not a great fit for SO. We tend to focus on questions about an actual development related problem you have faced. Please refer to [ask]. On-topic: what is it you're trying to see that the Azure portal or Application Insights will not provide? Also, please have a look at [Monitor Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring)

Comment: I am sorry for silly question. I just started as junior dev and got first time working with cloud. I will be careful in future asking question in proper manner. And Yes Application insight provides data I am looking for but only in azure portal. I am looking for a way to get azure function insight using REST API call if I pass invocationId or something similar.

Comment: My main objective is to check once Function is invoked I want to keep checking if function is still running or finished execution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp) with their [Async HTTP APIs pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#async-http) - it allows you to either provide your own invocationId or to use the one returned from orchestrator start.

Comment: yes looked into that, but I am looking for a way to constantly check if invoked activity function is finished executing or not using invocation.

Comment: Not sure if I am getting your point correctly, but if you need to constantly check (as a "background job") if the function has finished, you can use both Async HTTP APIs pattern I have mentioned before and [Monitor pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#monitoring) to check if that function is still running. Other way around would be to just poll the function status with some interval.